# psycopg insert timestamp without formatting it

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a timestamp that I'm trying to insert into postgres using psycopg, but I'm having trouble getting things to work out and I think it's because I'm trying to use python's string formatting to drop the date into the right position. I have something like this

```
values = {"timestamp": u'2016-03-01T12:40:45.236697', ...}
"INSERT...VALUES(...{timestamp}...)".format(**values)
```

Postgres is tripping up on the "T", throwing a syntax error.

I've tried converting the string to a datetime object, but then the formatting just puts it back into a string that looks like this

```
2016-03-01 12:40:45.236697
```

and postgres hangs up on the space. I've tried to use PGs to_timestamp(), but PG hangs up in the same places. I'll end up with a few of these and I'm trying to avoid breaking this out into several strings that I have to concat back together. Does anyone have any ideas? I can manipulate the original timestamp string if I need to, but I can't figure out what that string should look like to make PG happy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not format your string like that. As Ilja mentions in a comment you are vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks that way. You should instead pass the dictionary as the second argument to `.execute()`, e.g.:

```
import datetime as dt
t = u'2016-03-01T12:40:45.236697'
cur.execute(
    """INSERT INTO your_table (timestamp, ...)
        VALUES (%(timestamp)s, ...);""",
     {'timestamp': dt.datetime.strptime(t,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'), ...})
```

This ensures that the correct datatype is inserted and psycopg2 handles the escaping for you.

Comment: Thanks, Bernie. This is an internal api and we control all the content going in, so I wasn't even thinking about SQL injection, but I should have known there was a better way. I'll dig more into the psycopg2 docs.

Comment: @gignosko: you're most welcome. I wish you luck with the psycopg2 docs! Happy coding to you :-)